# What does the code img src="'.$target.'" mean?

Tags: php

```
 <?php
    define('upload', 'images/');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

         $name=$_POST['name'];
         $score=$_POST['score'];
         $screenshoot=$_FILES['screenshoot']['name'];
         $target=upload.$screenshoot;
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshoot']['tmp_name'], $target);           
         if(!empty($name)&&!empty($score)){
          $dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','57317019','guitar_game');
          $query="INSERT INTO guitargame(id,date,name,score,screenshoot".
          "values(0,NOW(),'$name','$score','$screenshoot')";
          $result= mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

          mysqli_close($dbc);
            }
         else{
            echo "Please fill out all the blanks";
             }

          }

         echo "<p>Thanks for adding your new high score!</p>";
         echo "<p><strong>Name:</strong>"."$name</p>";
         echo "<p><strong>Score:</strong>"."$score</p>";
         echo '<img src="'.$target.'">';
         echo '<p><a href="index.php">Back to high scores</a></p>';
       ?>
```

l wanna asked what does the `img src="'.$target.'"` means? Why not use `img src="$target"` instead? Thanks in advance! I am new to php.

Comment: Because the outer string is using single quotes and $vars are not expanded in single quotes

Comment: why don't you "Google that"? and start accepting answers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not sure just marking this as a "duplicate" will really help Mr.tang learn...

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it might be hard for a new comer to know how to google that - he is effectively asking when to use string interpolation vs concatenation. Also, the 'duplicate' question does not answer the question of when to use one over the other.

Comment: @wogsland This answer in the duplicate I closed it with http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446229/1415724 contains that explanation.

Comment: @Bryan See that also ^ ^ ^

Comment: @ All: This OP has a bad track record and does not do the necessary research before asking, nor do they mark any questions as solved; such as this one won't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The difference between

```
echo '<img src="'.$target.'">';
```

and

```
echo "<img src=\"$target\">";
```

is that in the former strings are concatenated whereas in the latter the double quotes need to be escaped inside the string to use double quotes which are required to process the variable inside the string. Using just `img src="$target"` would not work in the `echo` in either case.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:

```
echo '<img src="'.$target.'">';
```

gives an equal result to

```
echo "<img src=\"$target\">";
```

Longer answer: the PHP parser looks inside the `"..."`-style tags for any variables to replace. It doesn't look inside the `'...'`-style tags. So the latter is a bit faster. You will only notice a difference when this is inside a loop that is executed hundreds of times.